Error: El formulario multipart enviado es incorrecto al intentar obtener un COT de ARBA (Argentina)
Me estoy rompiendo el coco con esto. Tengo un archivo generado para obtener el COT.
Si lo posteo usando un form normal, todo funciona ok
<form method="post" action="http://cot.test.arba.gov.ar/TransporteBienes/SeguridadCliente/presentarRemitos.do" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div><input type="text" name="user" value="30xxxxxx9" /></div>
    <div><input type="text" name="password" value="xxxxxx" /></div>
    <div><input type="file" name="file" /></div>
    <div><input type="submit" name="Postear" style="padding: 5px 15px" /></div>
</form>

Pero si intento hacerlo programaticamente, me devuelve un error
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<TBError>
  <tipoError>DATO</tipoError>
  <codigoError>87</codigoError>
  <mensajeError>El formulario multipart enviado es incorrecto. Verifique las especifiaciones para la aplicación cliente.</mensajeError>
</TBError>

Esta es la versión más simple del código, pero ya probé de todas las maneras posibles de postear un form
    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    public ActionResult TestCOTProgramaticamente( bool TestEnviroment ) {
        var testUrl = "http://cot.test.arba.gov.ar/TransporteBienes/SeguridadCliente/presentarRemitos.do";
        var productionUrl = "https://cot.arba.gov.ar/TransporteBienes/SeguridadCliente/presentarRemitos.do";
        var filename = "TB_30xxxxxx9_000001_20241126_000001.txt";
        var filenameWithPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/content/temp/"), filename);

        var testFormData = new MultipartFormDataContent {
            { new StringContent("30xxxxxx9"), "user" },
            { new StringContent("xxxxxx"), "password" },
            { GetFileContent(filenameWithPath), "file", filename }
        };

        return Content(PostToUrl(testUrl, testFormData));
    }

    private StreamContent GetFileContent(string filePath) {
        var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        var streamContent = new StreamContent(fileStream);
        streamContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data");
        return streamContent;
    }

    private string PostToUrl(string url, MultipartFormDataContent formData) {
        var response = client.PostAsync(url, formData).Result;
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }

Posteandolo al ambiente de producción me da el mismo error.
Edit: también probé usando "\"user\"", pero tampoco funcionó.
Otra prueba que hice fue seteando el charset: streamContent.Headers.ContentType.CharSet = "ISO-8859-1" tampoco funcionó
¿alguien lo tiene funcionando que me pueda ayudar?

En un mundo ideal, deberías resolver esta duda con la documentación y en último caso deberías poder contactar con la gente que provee el servicio.
Revisé "la documentación", visité el sitio en cuestión, el cual tiene casi todo caído. Probé la API e incluso con login incorrecto da un código 200. Así que no me cabe duda de que esto fue desarrollados por simios.

Tu código no tiene grandes problemas, se envían los datos satisfactoriamente y seguramente ellos hacen una validación la cual detecta un "problema" y te envía el mensaje de error.
Como tu código es capaz de logearse (no te da ese error) descartamos problemas en la confección de las variables user y password
Como has señalado que al hacerlo desde un form normal funciona, descartamos un problema con los datos internos del archivo.
Entonces, probablemente el problema sucede en la cabecera del fichero a enviar.
Primero aclarar que al menos tienes 2 cabeceras que son para cosas distintas

La cabecera del envío (request), esta debe ser multipart/form-data, esto lo coloca automáticamente al usar MultipartFormDataContent
La cabecera del archivo que debe ser text/plain

Cuando haces:
streamContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data");

Estas seteando la cabecera del archivo, por lo que lo debes cambiar a:
streamContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain");


Con mucha suerte esto debería resolver el problema, pero si no es así lo que debes hacer es generar exactamente las mismas cabeceras que se envía desde el navegador
Por ejemplo, Edge enviará esta cabecera para el archivo:
Content-Disposition, form-data; name="file"; filename="nombreArchivo.txt"

En cambio, C# con HttpClient envía:
Content-Disposition, form-data; name=file; filename=welcome.txt; filename*=utf-8''welcome.txt

Notar la falta de comillas dobles y que repite el filename agregando al segundo un UTF8
Dado que el nombre del archivo es un dato importante (y el asunto está construido por simios), también podríamos suponer que esto puede dar un problema. Para corregirlo usamos el siguiente código:
private  StreamContent GetFileContent(string filePath,string filename)
{
    var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    var streamContent = new StreamContent(fileStream);
    streamContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain");
    streamContent.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition",
        new string(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"{filename}\"").
        Select(b => (char)b).ToArray()));
    return streamContent;
}

Esto nos dará un Content-Disposition igual al del navegador.
Si esto no funciona, debes seguir agregando elementos (probablemente) cabeceras para que quede exactamente igual

Gracias Yussef, ya lo tengo más o menos solucionado armando el request a mano (haciendo una composición de strings). Pero cada cosita diferente te da error o no. Una locura. Cuando lo tenga bien testeado lo voy a poner como respuesta si a alguien más le ayuda.

No son simios... son desarrolladores estatales.. y sufren con 1000000 cosas a la vez desgraciadamente :(
